# Is it bad practice for an application to read its own log?

Tags: logging

I have a requirement for my application to be able to find out if changes have happened to a complex tree of objects since a specific time. Changes can be any kind of things: updates, deletes, even views.

I could add some structure to write these events to my database with a timestamp, and then be able to reason about changes from that, but why should I create a database table for something that so closely resembles a system log?

Instead, I am thinking of simply using the programs log file. I'll read the latest entry that matches a specific pattern (so I know the entry is about one of the changes, I am looking for), and if the timestamp is later than my checkpoint, I know changes have occured since my checkpoint.

This is pretty simple, but I am unsure whether there is something I havn't thought about. One thing is that I need to make sure that the logging level is set so that the messages actually appear in the log, but that shouldn't be much of a problem. I could have several logfiles, where I make sure to include absolutely everything in one of them, and let the other be customizable.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it would work as long as you are not attempting to write to it at the same time (use historical logs only), but that defeats the purpose of a log file.  You may be expecting exceptions tracing and all sorts of other junk in there which may confuse your parsing of it.  I would definitely recommend to write to a separate data log, which would be controlled by your application in terms of the cleanliness of the data.

Take for example if you data is being written to the system log and an error occurs which display "this data: ... has an error".  Your parsing may read a duplicate copy of it, or worse if you had other developers dumping this information, you may not be able to control over this.

Comment: Indeed. It would be optimal to store entries for this use pattern in its own logfile with no other types of entries. And writing would become a problem, that is true, but that would never be relevant to this specific case. Thanks for your inputs

Comment: "It will never happen" isn't the right attitude.  Consider what happens when an exception occurs, or other forces are at work beyond your control.

Comment: Well sure, but in this case, the domain for exceptions is rather small. Not hard to avoid through resillient coding

Comment: I'm not denying you can get it to work for your situation, but your question relates to "good practice", which should be applicable to applications of all shapes and sizes.